# vue double curly braces to print/echo an input search term

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3

On my first vue training. Maybe it is the most obvious question... how can i print the input text (the search term typed in the input field) over using the double curly braces {{}} in the App.vue file?

This is the APP.vue

```html
<template>
  <SearchBar @emitTermSearch="onTermSearch"></SearchBar>
</template>

<script>
import SearchBar from "./components/SearchBar";
export default {
  name: "App",
  components: {
    SearchBar
  },
  methods: {
    onTermSearch(emitTermSearch) {
      console.log(emitTermSearch);
    }
  }
};
</script>
```

This is the SearchBar.vue

```html
<div id="searchbar">
    <input @input="onInput" />
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: "SearchBar",
  methods: {
    onInput(event) {
      this.$emit("emitTermSearch", event.target.value);
    }
  }
};
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can store it as a variable

```html
<template>
  <SearchBar @emitTermSearch="onTermSearch"></SearchBar>
  {{searchVal}}
</template>

<script>
import SearchBar from "./components/SearchBar";
export default {
  name: "App",
  components: {
    SearchBar
  },
  data():{
    return{
      searchVal: null
    }
  },
  methods: {
    onTermSearch(emitTermSearch) {
      this.searchVal = emitTermSearch;
    }
  }
};
</script>
```

Comment: in Angular this is done in such a simple way... i find vue very difficult i must say... Thank you for your solution!!!